# How to force a neutral value if the attribute used in Mongodb aggregation is not existing?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have to make an aggregation like that:

```
Game.aggregate([{
                        $match: {
                            "_id": {
                                "$in": result.games
                            }
                        }
                    },
                        {
                            $unwind: "$gamers",
                        },
                        {
                            $group: {
                                _id: {
                                    $month: "$gamers.playedAt",
                                },
                                count: {
                                    $sum: 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ])
```

Yet, in the `gamers` array when an element has not the attribute `playedAt` , the query fails with:

```
MongoError: can't convert from BSON type missing to Date
```

How to force a  neutral  value (0 for example) when  `playedAt` is not defined ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$cond` like a ternary operator.

additionally you can also check the data type of `playedAt` is date using BSON `$type : 9`

```
_id : { 
    { $cond: [ "$gamers.playedAt", {$month : "$gamers.playedAt"}, 0 ] } 
}
```